# I can't save my vim file?

Tags: vim, editor

I'm new in VIM editor, and i want to know how to save a file after editing, i entered `:x`
after finishing my modification, but nothing is happening !! so where should i put this command `:x` to be executed !

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command for saving a Vim file is `:w` and Enter in the Command mode. You can get the command mode by pressing the Esc key. If you want to save and exit the file it is `:wq`

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> before in order to enter into a normal mode, then press <kbd>:</kbd> to enter into a command mode, then enter your command (`x` in this case) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.